# How to solve two IntegerPart function in Reduce?

Tags: equation-solving

Here I have two Functions, which involve IntegerPart.
For example:

```
f[x_] := IntegerPart[-0.002*x*(x - 1000)]
q[x_] := IntegerPart[-0.002*x*(x - 2000)]
```

Then I want to get the answer that satisfies "f[x]==35,(0<=x<1807)", the code is as follows:

```
Simplify[Reduce[Rationalize[(f[k] == 35) && (0 <= k < 1807)], k, 
   Integers, 
   Method -> {"DiscreteSolutionBound" -> 1000001}]] // ToString
```

The answer is k==18 || k==982.

Also, if I want to get the answer that satisfies "q[x]==35,(0<=x<2500)", the code is as follows:

```
Simplify[Reduce[Rationalize[(q[k] == 35) && (0 <= k < 2500)], k, 
   Integers, 
   Method -> {"DiscreteSolutionBound" -> 1000001}]] // ToString
```

The answer is k==9 || k==1991

But, here I want to get the pair of answers (k,m) that satisfies "f[x]==q[m],(0<=x< 1807), (0<=m<2500)", so I write the code as follows:

```
Simplify[Reduce[
  Rationalize[(f[k] == q[m]) && (0 <= k < 1807) && (0 <= m < 
      2500)], {k, m}, Integers, 
  Method -> {"DiscreteSolutionBound" -> 1000001}]]
```

It takes a lot of time to calculate the results, and return the information as follows:
[image]

**So, How can I solve this equation and get the answer pair (k,m) in an elegant way?**

Answer (score 2):

Two easy solutions are 0,0 and 2,1. You can use `FindInstance`:

```
f[x_] := IntegerPart[Rationalize[-0.002]*x*(x - 1000)]
q[x_] := IntegerPart[Rationalize[-0.002]*x*(x - 2000)]

FindInstance[f[k] == q[m] && (0 <= k < 1807) && (0 <= m < 2500), {k, m}, NonNegativeIntegers]

(* {{k -> 0, m -> 0}} *)
```

...or you could do a minimize like this. Here I've made k,m larger than 2,1 so we look for larger solutions:

```
NMinimize[{(f[k] - q[m])^2, (2 < k < 1807) && (1 < m < 2500)}, {k ∈ Integers, m ∈ Integers}]
(* err must be zero *)
(* {0., {k -> 651, m -> 121}} *)

f[651] == q[121]
(* True *)
```

There aren't too many pairs that you couldn't just brute force it:

```
result = ParallelMap[(f[#[[1]]] - q[#[[2]]]) &, 
   Outer[List, Range[0, 1807 - 1], Range[0, 2500 - 1]], {2}];

Length@Position[result, 0]
(* 667 solutions *)

(* test a random solution - need to sub 1,1 from position *)
f[#[[1]]] == q[#[[2]]] &@(RandomChoice[Position[result, 0]] - {1, 1})
(* True *)
```

Here are all the solutions if you don't want to evaluate that yourself:

```
{{0, 0}, {0, 2000}, {2, 1}, {2, 1999}, {4, 2}, {4, 1998}, {6, 3}, {6, 1997}, {8, 4}, {8, 1996}, {10, 5}, {10, 1995}, {12, 6}, {12, 1994}, {14, 7}, {14, 1993}, {16, 8}, {16, 1992}, {18, 9}, {18, 1991}, {20, 10}, {20, 1990}, {22, 11}, {22, 1989}, {33, 16}, {33, 1984}, {35, 17}, {35, 1983}, {37, 18}, {37, 1982}, {46, 22}, {46, 1978}, {52, 25}, {52, 1975}, {54, 26}, {54, 1974}, {61, 29}, {61, 1971}, {63, 30}, {63, 1970}, {67, 32}, {67, 1968}, {72, 34}, {72, 1966}, {74, 35}, {74, 1965}, {79, 37}, {79, 1963}, {83, 39}, {83, 1961}, {88, 41}, {88, 1959}, {93, 43}, {93, 1957}, {97, 45}, {97, 1955}, {102, 47}, {102, 1953}, {105, 48}, {105, 1952}, {107, 49}, {107, 1951}, {110, 50}, {110, 1950}, {112, 51}, {112, 1949}, {114, 52}, {114, 1948}, {117, 53}, {117, 1947}, {124, 56}, {124, 1944}, {127, 57}, {127, 1943}, {132, 59}, {132, 1941}, {134, 60}, {134, 1940}, {137, 61}, {137, 1939}, {140, 62}, {140, 1938}, {145, 64}, {145, 1936}, {150, 66}, {150, 1934}, {153, 67}, {153, 1933}, {158, 69}, {158, 1931}, {161, 70}, {161, 1930}, {175, 75}, {175, 1925}, {178, 76}, {178, 1924}, {181, 77}, {181, 1923}, {183, 78}, {183, 1922}, {190, 80}, {190, 1920}, {192, 81}, {192, 1919}, {199, 83}, {199, 1917}, {201, 84}, {201, 1916}, {205, 85}, {205, 1915}, {208, 86}, {208, 1914}, {211, 87}, {211, 1913}, {214, 88}, {214, 1912}, {218, 89}, {218, 1911}, {220, 90}, {220, 1910}, {224, 91}, {224, 1909}, {230, 93}, {230, 1907}, {234, 94}, {234, 1906}, {237, 95}, {237, 1905}, {241, 96}, {241, 1904}, {245, 97}, {245, 1903}, {248, 98}, {248, 1902}, {252, 99}, {252, 1901}, {256, 100}, {256, 1900}, {259, 101}, {259, 1899}, {263, 102}, {263, 1898}, {266, 103}, {266, 1897}, {270, 104}, {270, 1896}, {274, 105}, {274, 1895}, {278, 106}, {278, 1894}, {283, 107}, {283, 1893}, {286, 108}, {286, 1892}, {291, 109}, {291, 1891}, {294, 110}, {294, 1890}, {295, 110}, {295, 1890}, {299, 111}, {299, 1889}, {303, 112}, {303, 1888}, {308, 113}, {308, 1887}, {313, 114}, {313, 1886}, {314, 114}, {314, 1886}, {317, 115}, {317, 1885}, {318, 115}, {318, 1885}, {323, 116}, {323, 1884}, {327, 117}, {327, 1883}, {328, 117}, {328, 1883}, {333, 118}, {333, 1882}, {334, 118}, {334, 1882}, {338, 119}, {338, 1881}, {344, 120}, {344, 1880}, {345, 120}, {345, 1880}, {349, 121}, {349, 1879}, {356, 122}, {356, 1878}, {361, 123}, {361, 1877}, {362, 123}, {362, 1877}, {368, 124}, {368, 1876}, {369, 124}, {369, 1876}, {374, 125}, {374, 1875}, {375, 125}, {375, 1875}, {382, 126}, {382, 1874}, {383, 126}, {383, 1874}, {389, 127}, {389, 1873}, {390, 127}, {390, 1873}, {398, 128}, {398, 1872}, {399, 128}, {399, 1872}, {406, 129}, {406, 1871}, {407, 129}, {407, 1871}, {417, 130}, {417, 1870}, {418, 130}, {418, 1870}, {419, 130}, {419, 1870}, {426, 131}, {426, 1869}, {427, 131}, {427, 1869}, {428, 131}, {428, 1869}, {429, 131}, {429, 1869}, {441, 132}, {441, 1868}, {442, 132}, {442, 1868}, {443, 132}, {443, 1868}, {444, 132}, {444, 1868}, {445, 132}, {445, 1868}, {456, 133}, {456, 1867}, {457, 133}, {457, 1867}, {458, 133}, {458, 1867}, {459, 133}, {459, 1867}, {460, 133}, {460, 1867}, {461, 133}, {461, 1867}, {500, 134}, {500, 1866}, {539, 133}, {539, 1867}, {540, 133}, {540, 1867}, {541, 133}, {541, 1867}, {542, 133}, {542, 1867}, {543, 133}, {543, 1867}, {544, 133}, {544, 1867}, {555, 132}, {555, 1868}, {556, 132}, {556, 1868}, {557, 132}, {557, 1868}, {558, 132}, {558, 1868}, {559, 132}, {559, 1868}, {571, 131}, {571, 1869}, {572, 131}, {572, 1869}, {573, 131}, {573, 1869}, {574, 131}, {574, 1869}, {581, 130}, {581, 1870}, {582, 130}, {582, 1870}, {583, 130}, {583, 1870}, {593, 129}, {593, 1871}, {594, 129}, {594, 1871}, {601, 128}, {601, 1872}, {602, 128}, {602, 1872}, {610, 127}, {610, 1873}, {611, 127}, {611, 1873}, {617, 126}, {617, 1874}, {618, 126}, {618, 1874}, {625, 125}, {625, 1875}, {626, 125}, {626, 1875}, {631, 124}, {631, 1876}, {632, 124}, {632, 1876}, {638, 123}, {638, 1877}, {639, 123}, {639, 1877}, {644, 122}, {644, 1878}, {651, 121}, {651, 1879}, {655, 120}, {655, 1880}, {656, 120}, {656, 1880}, {662, 119}, {662, 1881}, {666, 118}, {666, 1882}, {667, 118}, {667, 1882}, {672, 117}, {672, 1883}, {673, 117}, {673, 1883}, {677, 116}, {677, 1884}, {682, 115}, {682, 1885}, {683, 115}, {683, 1885}, {686, 114}, {686, 1886}, {687, 114}, {687, 1886}, {692, 113}, {692, 1887}, {697, 112}, {697, 1888}, {701, 111}, {701, 1889}, {705, 110}, {705, 1890}, {706, 110}, {706, 1890}, {709, 109}, {709, 1891}, {714, 108}, {714, 1892}, {717, 107}, {717, 1893}, {722, 106}, {722, 1894}, {726, 105}, {726, 1895}, {730, 104}, {730, 1896}, {734, 103}, {734, 1897}, {737, 102}, {737, 1898}, {741, 101}, {741, 1899}, {744, 100}, {744, 1900}, {748, 99}, {748, 1901}, {752, 98}, {752, 1902}, {755, 97}, {755, 1903}, {759, 96}, {759, 1904}, {763, 95}, {763, 1905}, {766, 94}, {766, 1906}, {770, 93}, {770, 1907}, {776, 91}, {776, 1909}, {780, 90}, {780, 1910}, {782, 89}, {782, 1911}, {786, 88}, {786, 1912}, {789, 87}, {789, 1913}, {792, 86}, {792, 1914}, {795, 85}, {795, 1915}, {799, 84}, {799, 1916}, {801, 83}, {801, 1917}, {808, 81}, {808, 1919}, {810, 80}, {810, 1920}, {817, 78}, {817, 1922}, {819, 77}, {819, 1923}, {822, 76}, {822, 1924}, {825, 75}, {825, 1925}, {839, 70}, {839, 1930}, {842, 69}, {842, 1931}, {847, 67}, {847, 1933}, {850, 66}, {850, 1934}, {855, 64}, {855, 1936}, {860, 62}, {860, 1938}, {863, 61}, {863, 1939}, {866, 60}, {866, 1940}, {868, 59}, {868, 1941}, {873, 57}, {873, 1943}, {876, 56}, {876, 1944}, {883, 53}, {883, 1947}, {886, 52}, {886, 1948}, {888, 51}, {888, 1949}, {890, 50}, {890, 1950}, {893, 49}, {893, 1951}, {895, 48}, {895, 1952}, {898, 47}, {898, 1953}, {903, 45}, {903, 1955}, {907, 43}, {907, 1957}, {912, 41}, {912, 1959}, {917, 39}, {917, 1961}, {921, 37}, {921, 1963}, {926, 35}, {926, 1965}, {928, 34}, {928, 1966}, {933, 32}, {933, 1968}, {937, 30}, {937, 1970}, {939, 29}, {939, 1971}, {946, 26}, {946, 1974}, {948, 25}, {948, 1975}, {954, 22}, {954, 1978}, {963, 18}, {963, 1982}, {965, 17}, {965, 1983}, {967, 16}, {967, 1984}, {978, 11}, {978, 1989}, {980, 10}, {980, 1990}, {982, 9}, {982, 1991}, {984, 8}, {984, 1992}, {986, 7}, {986, 1993}, {988, 6}, {988, 1994}, {990, 5}, {990, 1995}, {992, 4}, {992, 1996}, {994, 3}, {994, 1997}, {996, 2}, {996, 1998}, {998, 1}, {998, 1999}, {1000, 0}, {1000, 2000}, {1002, 2001}, {1004, 2002}, {1006, 2003}, {1008, 2004}, {1010, 2005}, {1012, 2006}, {1014, 2007}, {1016, 2008}, {1018, 2009}, {1020, 2010}, {1022, 2011}, {1033, 2017}, {1035, 2018}, {1037, 2019}, {1050, 2026}, {1052, 2027}, {1054, 2028}, {1065, 2034}, {1067, 2035}, {1072, 2038}, {1076, 2040}, {1081, 2043}, {1083, 2044}, {1085, 2045}, {1090, 2048}, {1092, 2049}, {1094, 2050}, {1099, 2053}, {1106, 2057}, {1113, 2061}, {1120, 2065}, {1123, 2067}, {1125, 2068}, {1132, 2072}, {1135, 2074}, {1137, 2075}, {1140, 2077}, {1142, 2078}, {1145, 2080}, {1147, 2081}, {1150, 2083}, {1152, 2084}, {1155, 2086}, {1157, 2087}, {1160, 2089}, {1162, 2090}, {1165, 2092}, {1167, 2093}, {1175, 2098}, {1180, 2101}, {1188, 2106}, {1196, 2111}, {1199, 2113}, {1207, 2118}, {1210, 2120}, {1212, 2121}, {1215, 2123}, {1218, 2125}, {1229, 2132}, {1232, 2134}, {1235, 2136}, {1249, 2145}, {1252, 2147}, {1255, 2149}, {1258, 2151}, {1261, 2153}, {1272, 2160}, {1273, 2161}, {1281, 2166}, {1282, 2167}, {1291, 2173}, {1297, 2177}, {1300, 2179}, {1303, 2181}, {1309, 2185}, {1319, 2192}, {1322, 2194}, {1332, 2201}, {1335, 2203}, {1338, 2205}, {1345, 2210}, {1355, 2217}, {1362, 2222}, {1365, 2224}, {1368, 2226}, {1372, 2229}, {1379, 2234}, {1382, 2236}, {1389, 2241}, {1396, 2246}, {1400, 2249}, {1403, 2251}, {1407, 2254}, {1414, 2259}, {1418, 2262}, {1422, 2265}, {1448, 2284}, {1452, 2287}, {1460, 2293}, {1463, 2295}, {1468, 2299}, {1471, 2301}, {1479, 2307}, {1483, 2310}, {1492, 2317}, {1496, 2320}, {1500, 2323}, {1504, 2326}, {1508, 2329}, {1512, 2332}, {1516, 2335}, {1520, 2338}, {1525, 2342}, {1533, 2348}, {1537, 2351}, {1546, 2358}, {1555, 2365}, {1559, 2368}, {1563, 2371}, {1564, 2372}, {1568, 2375}, {1577, 2382}, {1582, 2386}, {1586, 2389}, {1591, 2393}, {1600, 2400}, {1605, 2404}, {1609, 2407}, {1610, 2408}, {1614, 2411}, {1619, 2415}, {1628, 2422}, {1629, 2423}, {1643, 2434}, {1648, 2438}, {1653, 2442}, {1658, 2446}, {1663, 2450}, {1668, 2454}, {1673, 2458}, {1679, 2463}, {1683, 2466}, {1689, 2471}, {1694, 2475}, {1700, 2480}, {1705, 2484}, {1710, 2488}, {1715, 2492}, {1720, 2496}}
```

Comment: Just to compare: `Table[FindInstance[
  Rationalize[(f[k] - q[m] == 0 && f[k] == a), 
    0] && (0 <= k < 1807) && (0 <= m < 2500), {k, m}, 
  NonNegativeIntegers, 10], {a, 6, 10}]` performs `{373.641, {{}, {{k -> 4, m -> 2}, {k -> 4, m -> 1998}, {k -> 996, 
    m -> 2}, {k -> 996, m -> 1998}}, {}, {}, {}}}`.

Comment: `result` is executed in 229.409 s.

Comment: I have many equations like this. So if I want to get all the answer pairs, what is the simplest way?